# Can't stop thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupted-exception

I'm trying to create a thread and then interrupt it. But it doesn't stop and cause exception. Can anybody explain what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Add your code here - добавь код тут
        TestThread test = new TestThread();
        test.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        test.interrupt();

    }

    public static class TestThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("I did the Thread");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cause exception. What exception ?

Comment: Seems to [work fine](https://ideone.com/MCQLFw).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Maybe when you executed it, thread was running when interrupt was executed. Did you run it a couple of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `internal flag` gets resetted after calling `interrupt`.
You have to call it again in your catch of the `thread`.
The topic was also covered in [the Java Specialists Newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html)

> In my example, after I caught the InterruptedException, I used
>   Thread.currentThread().interrupt() to immediately interrupted the
>   thread again. Why is this necessary? When the exception is thrown, the
>   interrupted flag is cleared, so if you have nested loops, you will
>   cause trouble in the outer loops

Something like this should work:

```
   try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("I did the Thread");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.interrupt();
           // No need for break
        }
```

This makes sure that the rest of the code is executed.

Answer (score 3):

According to [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--):

> A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive at the
>   time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method returning
>   false.

Since you sleep the thread for 1000ms, when you call `test.interrupt()`, thread is asleep, almost all the times. So `InterruptedException` will be thrown. Therefore you should exit the loop at the catch clause.

Include a `break` when you catch `InterruptedException` to exit while loop.

```
 while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("I did the Thread");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
```